# is it possible to get the project root dir in python fastapi app

Tags: python

My python3 fastapi project root dir is `'/Users/john/source/reddwarf/backend/chat-server/'`
.  I am tried to get the python project root dir like this:

```
root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

but the dir is `'/Users/john/source/reddwarf/backend/chat-server/src/tool/graphics'`. I also tried this code:

```
root1 = os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
```

but the dir is `'/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn'`, is it possible to get the project dir path? what should I do?

Comment: You can combine the `__filename__` magic with os.path.join and `..` to derive the actual root path.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the root of the project using the following code:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

You can also access different directories by using the following code:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
```